# How to write this notation in latex, can anybody help me, I assume it is a greek alphabet?

Tags: tables, equations, annotations

May I ask, how to write this notation in latex? Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: That's just `$\Theta^p$`, probably with a Times-like font.

Comment: Definitely the base of this power is the greek letter `theta`. I am sure because my native language is Greek. Campa is right!

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}` if you use pdfLatex.

Comment: @Miktos: more precisely an uppercase theta.

Comment: @Bernard Yes that's correct! An uppercase theta!

Comment: Perhaps one (or more) of you commentators could provide an answer so that others might notice the solution. --- GOM